# How can I implement this autoscope template object better?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have this idea for an auto-scoped type that will clean up resources when they leave scope or the containing object is destructed.

This is what it is currently:

```
template <typename RESOURCE, typename DELETEOR>
struct autoscope
{
    RESOURCE m_resource;
    DELETEOR const& m_deleteor;

    autoscope(RESOURCE resource, DELETEOR const& deleteor)
        : m_resource(resource)
        , m_deleteor(deleteor)
    {
    }

    operator RESOURCE()
    {
        return m_resource;
    }

    ~autoscope()
    {
        m_deleteor(m_resource);
    }
};

template <typename RESOURCE, typename DELETEOR>
autoscope<RESOURCE, DELETEOR> make_autoscope(RESOURCE resource, DELETEOR deleteor)
{
    return autoscope<RESOURCE, DELETEOR>(resource, deleteor);
}
```

A couple of potential/real problems I see/have come across.

1. For each resource that is handled, there is an DELETOR object or pointer created.  I'm not sure if an optimizer will junk that and just inline the DELETOR functor or function pointer so that the autoscope object will not be larger than the RESOURCE handle. I'm not sure that the compiler is allowed to, but I don't think it is possible to have the DELETOR *just passed* as a type.
2. I tried to pass an `HICON` and the function pointer `DestroyIcon()` and it crashed.  When debugging it showed that the pointer passed to `make_autoscope()` was `0x755225e0 {user32.dll!_DestroyCursor@4}`, which is obviously wrong.  Is this a VC++ problem (2013)?  Or is there something else wrong?

I'm currently using VC++ in VS2013, but this should be portable.

## EDIT

Ok, I've thought up some ideas based on the comments.  Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
template <typename RESOURCE, typename CRTP, RESOURCE invalid>
struct autoscope
{
protected:
    RESOURCE m_res;
public:
    autoscope()
        : m_res(invalid)
    {
    }

    autoscope(RESOURCE res)
        : m_res(res)
    {
    }

    autoscope(autoscope&& move)
    {
        std::swap(move.m_res, m_res);
    }

    autoscope(autoscope& copy) = delete;

    operator RESOURCE() const
    {
        return m_res;
    }

    RESOURCE get() const
    {
        return m_res;
    }

    RESOURCE operator =(RESOURCE res)
    {
        set(res);
    }

    void set(RESOURCE res)
    {
        static_cast<CRTP*>(this)->delete_resource();
        m_res = res;
    }

    RESOURCE release()
    {
        RESOURCE result = m_res;
        m_res = invalid;
        return result;
    }

    ~autoscope()
    {
        static_cast<CRTP*>(this)->delete_resource();
    }

    operator bool() const
    {
        return m_res != (RESOURCE)0;
    }

    bool valid() const
    {
        return m_res != invalid;
    }
};

template <typename RESOURCE, BOOL(WINAPI *fn_delete)(RESOURCE), RESOURCE invalid = (RESOURCE)-1>
struct autoscope_bool : public autoscope<RESOURCE, autoscope_bool<RESOURCE, fn_delete, invalid>, invalid>
{
    typedef autoscope<RESOURCE, autoscope_bool, invalid> base;
    autoscope_bool()
        : base(invalid)
    {
    }

    autoscope_bool(RESOURCE res)
        : base(res)
    {
    }

    autoscope_bool(autoscope_bool&& move)
        : base(std::forward<autoscope_bool>(move))
    {
    }

    autoscope_bool(autoscope_bool& copy) = delete;

    void delete_resource()
    {
        if (base::m_res && base::m_res != invalid)
        {
            VERIFY(fn_delete(base::m_res));
            base::m_res = invalid;
        }
    }
};

template <typename RESOURCE, typename void(WINAPI *fn_delete)(RESOURCE), RESOURCE invalid = (RESOURCE)-1>
struct autoscope_void : autoscope<RESOURCE, autoscope_void<RESOURCE, fn_delete, invalid>, invalid>
{
    typedef autoscope<RESOURCE, autoscope_void, invalid> base;
    autoscope_void()
        : base(invalid)
    {
    }

    autoscope_void(RESOURCE res)
        : base(res)
    {
    }

    autoscope_void(autoscope_void&& move)
        : base(std::forward<autoscope_void>(move))
    {
    }

    autoscope_void(autoscope_void& copy) = delete;

    void delete_resource()
    {
        if (m_res != invalid)
        {
            VERIFY(fn_delete(m_res));
            m_res = invalid;
        }
    }
};

template <typename RESOURCE, typename FUNCTOR_DELETE, RESOURCE invalid = (RESOURCE)-1>
struct autoscope_functor : autoscope<RESOURCE, autoscope_functor<RESOURCE, FUNCTOR_DELETE, invalid>, invalid>
{
    typedef autoscope<RESOURCE, autoscope_functor, invalid> base;
private:
    FUNCTOR_DELETE m_functor_delete;
public:
    autoscope_functor(FUNCTOR_DELETE functor_delete)
        : autoscope(invalid)
        , m_functor_delete(functor_delete)
    {
    }

    autoscope_functor(RESOURCE res, FUNCTOR_DELETE functor_delete)
        : autoscope(res)
        , m_functor_delete(functor_delete)
    {
    }

    autoscope_functor(autoscope_functor&& move)
        : base(std::forward<autoscope_functor>(move))
        , m_functor_delete(move.m_functor_delete)
    {
    }

    autoscope_functor(autoscope_functor& copy) = delete;

    void delete_resource()
    {
        if (m_res != invalid)
        {
            m_functor_delete(m_res);
            m_res = invalid;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: In `make_autoscope`, you're binding the function parameter (which is passed by value) to the reference, hence returning a dangling reference.

Comment: The `HICON` thing reminded me of this ACCU article: http://accu.org/index.php/journals/2086

Comment: You should be able to replace `autoscope` with `unique_ptr<remove_pointer_t<HICON>, decltype(&::DestroyIcon)>`

Comment: @Praetorian That's problematic. `HICON` might not be a pointer type, for instance.

Comment: @dyp And more generally, stashing a reference is a terrible idea. Any time it's called with a temporary (e.g., a lambda expression), you end up with a dangling reference.

Comment: Also, [N4189](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4189.pdf) has a reasonable design, though the wording in that paper needs quite a bit of work.

Comment: @T.C. Really? When does that happen? AFAIK, if you have `STRICT` defined, then `HICON` is pointer to a struct named `HICON__` (or something like that), otherwise it is a `typedef` for `void *`. Didn't know there were cases where the WinAPI handle types were not pointers.

Comment: @Praetorian Perhaps not for HICON, but it's an opaque type and IMO better treated that way. Also, `unique_ptr<void, ...>` feels...icky, though I think that they specified `operator*` to make it work.

Comment: @Praetorian According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx), most HMEOWs are `HANDLE`s, which is in turn `PVOID`. `HFILE` is `int`, though, but I guess nobody uses it any more. Another issue is that `unique_ptr` checks for equality to `nullptr`, so it doesn't handle `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` cases.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for pointing out `HFILE`, I didn't know about that one. The rest of the info on that page is only partly correct. `HANDLE` is `PVOID` only if [`STRICT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not defined (and I think it is defined by default), otherwise each `HMEOW` is a pointer to a distinct type. I do know about the `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` mess, you end up writing a custom deleter to deal with that.

Comment: @Praetorian Of course, the STRICT page also says that "Without STRICT, all handles are defined as integers" ;) Broken documentation all around. The I_H_V mess also makes a bunch of `unique_ptr` member functions useless (like `explicit operator bool()`).

Comment: @T.C. hrm, I think I don't like N4189. I think there are designs that are more flexible that leverage the new `unhandled_exceptions` capability to allow different behaviours between normal function exits and abnormal, making them usable when you want your clean-up to have commit/rollback semantics.

Comment: @DrPizza, N4189 is a proposal, and still needs work.

Comment: @T.C. What's a HMEOW?  Can't find that name/acronym on the web.

Comment: So, I should have a separate specialization for a functor and a function pointer then.  With a function pointer, no reference is needed, it can just be  a template parameter, whereas the functor would have to be stored internally in the object.

Comment: `MEOW` is being used as a [metasyntactic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable).

Comment: @T.C. Ah, I just found that confusing especially since it wasn't really introduced as such.  I just thought you have figured out how to have a handle to your cat. ;)

Comment: IMHO, the StackOverflow Q&A model doesn't work well with appended questions. I think there are still issues in your new code, but adding a new answer here seems inappropriate to me. I'd suggest asking a new question. Please also consider asking on [CodeReview.Stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for code reviews (of working code).

Answer (score 2):

This needs a lot of work.

- The deleter definitely shouldn't be stored as a reference. That's a recipe for disaster, even if you fix `make_autoscope` to also take the deleter by reference. Any call to `make_autoscope` with a lambda as the deleter, and your code blows up.
- The copy and move operations need fixing. The default compiler-generated ones are definitely *not* suitable. This class should not be copyable, must be move constructible (for `make_autoscope` to work), and may or may not need to be move assignable.
- The interface can use some extra members, like `get()`, `reset()`, and  `release()`.
- I'm not sure there's much point in worrying about the size of the thing, but you can store the deleter and the resource in a compressed pair if you want. As for inlining, if the deleter is a function pointer, and the thing gets moved around, the compiler may not be able to inline the call. But that's nothing new.

Comment: *"Any call to make_autoscope with a lambda as the deleter, and your code blows up."* UB, but if the lambda is stateless, it probably won't be noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

c++11 already has what you need in `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>` and `shared_ptr<T>(T*, Deleter())`.

There is no reason whatsoever to reinvent the wheel here.

eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

auto main() -> int
{

    auto file_closer = [](FILE* fp) -> int
    {
        return std::fclose(fp);
    };

    // a unique_ptr who's custom deleter matches the signature of int fclose()
    using unique_auto_file = std::unique_ptr<FILE, int (*)(FILE*)>;
    unique_auto_file f(fopen("temp.txt", "r"), file_closer);

    // a shared_ptr to FILE
    using shared_auto_file = std::shared_ptr<FILE>;
    // construct with custom deleter (int-ignored) 
    shared_auto_file fs(fopen("temp.txt", "r"), file_closer);

    return 0;
}
```

note: updated as a result of @PeterSom's helpful comment

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to invent the wheel, starting from the fact that the resource is not necessarily a pointer.

Comment: ...in which case normal RAII encapsulation will be sufficient, trivial and succinct

Comment: While I upvoted the answer, it contains undefined behavior, because the C++ standard does not allow taking the address of a standard library fucntion. It needs to be wrapped in a deleter function (object). See https://wg21.link/p0551 R>=3) that will be in C++2a making it more clear that it is verboten. A standard library implementation can provide more overloads or additional parameters with default arguments to any standard library function. only the calls are required to work (with a few exceptions.

Comment: @PeterSom Interesting, thank you. I'll update the answer.